# How to obtain Guided Hand on a Monk

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, monk

Is there any way to get the Guided Hand feat on a monk character? My goal is to create a monk that will eventually utilize Wisdom for both attack and damage instead of Str/Dex. Right now I am looking at just purchasing a guided amulet of mighty fists, however I am not too certain if that is legal (dm discretion).

The idea came to mind when I discovered the [Guided Hand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/guided-hand/) and [Mythic Guided Hand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-feats/guided-hand-mythic/) feats, and I was wondering if anyone who had experience with getting X to Y knew of the quickest way to get to obtain this (if even possible).

> Prerequisite: Channel energy class feature, Channel Smite, proficiency with your deity’s favored weapon.

I want to obtain as many monk levels as possible without having to multi-class, but if I need to, then with the least amount necessary. My goals are to experiment with a build that will be on par with a power attack / str monk without the use of strength. (Simply to minimize MAD)

Comment: Is this a nromal monk or unchained monk?

Comment: Something to note is that Guided Hand doesn't actually add Wisdom to damage, just attack rolls.

Comment: @Forrestfire the mythic version does however. I do not know what deity has unarmed strike (or possibly natural attacks?) as its favored weapon?

Comment: Irori does, on Inner Sea Campaign Setting.

Comment: @Forrestfire The Mythic feat adds it into damage, and the campaign setting would include mythic feats

Comment: @Fering Either or! Both unchained and normal monk with archtypes are acceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Multi-classing to cleric

The easiest way is to multi-class cleric 1, you will gain all the requeriments for both [Channel Smite](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/channel-smite-combat/) and [Guided Hand](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/guided-hand/). A cleric of [Irori](http://pathfinder.wikia.com/wiki/Irori) (if using the *Inner Sea Campaign Setting*) grants unarmed strikes as favoured weapon.

If you do not want to take the core cleric, there are archetypes, like the [Crusader](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/archetypes/paizo-cleric-archetypes/crusader/) (bonus feat at 1st level and loses one domain), or the [Sacred Attendant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/archetypes/paizo-cleric-archetypes/sacred-attendant/) (+1 dodge to AC when unarmoured, but loses armor proficiencies and one domain).

### Guided weapon enhancement

You do not need *Guided Hand* to apply your wisdom to your melee attacks and damage rolls, the [Guided weapon enhancement](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/MagicWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Guided) (+1 bonus) can do that, and it can be applied on an [Amulet of Mighty Fists](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-mighty-fists/).

This quality appears on [Pathfinder Adventure Path #10](http://paizo.com/products/btpy82u9?Pathfinder-10-Curse-of-the-Crimson-Throne-Chapter-4-A-History-of-Ashes) (Curse of Crimson Throne #4), but has yet to be reprinted anywhere else. Maybe because it is a little *too strong* for a +1 enhancement cost and it was also written with *3.5 edition* in mind.

### Warpriest alternative

If you havent already, take a look on the [Sacred Fist Warpriest archetype](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Warpriest%20Sacred%20Fist), it replaces some class features for monk abilities, like *flurry of blows*, *style feats*, and *ki pool*. There are both benefits (6th level caster, swift action spells) and drawbacks (monk abilities and archetypes).

Warpriests have all requeriments for *channel smite* and *guided hand* aswell, as they gain favoured weapon, weapon focus on their chosen weapon and channel energy by spending fervor.

Comment: Good point. Actually, i will look into my copy of the anniversary edition later and see what they replaced it with for that npc.

Answer (score 2):

It might be out of reach, and might not solve your MAD problem, but it's worth noting that there IS a way to get channel energy purely through feats. Greater Eldritch Heritage (which unfortunately requires 17 Cha and 17th level, as well as 3 other feats) with the Solar bloodline grants the ability to channel energy. It's a bit easier if your DM will allow a wildblooded bloodline with Eldritch Heritage, as the Empyreal (Celestial) bloodline grants the ability to channel energy as a 9th level power, rather than 15th.

Also worth noting, if you are going to multiclass, there are a lot more options to gain channel energy than just cleric, even at 1st level. Druids, Inquisitors, Mediums, Oracles, Shamans, Spiritualists, Summoners, and Wizards can all acquire the ability to channel energy at 1st level, and Bards, Witches, and Vigilantes can at 2nd level (mostly through archetypes).

Comment: Channel Energy from racial feats doesn't seem to satisfy "as a class feature", so pretty sure neither of those bloodline feat ideas would work.

Answer (score 1):

Paizo has not published any way to accomplish this as a single-classed monk. No monk archetype offers channel energy, nor does any feat or magic item. A single level of cleric tends to be often be a decent choice anyway (though sadly not as good as it was in 3.5), so that’s probably the best you are going to do.